# Failed to access home page after moving WebContent to src/main/webapp

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

I've a web application built in Eclipse IDE using *Web > Dynamic Web Project* structure. The project runs under WildFly 10.0 server. The web resources were stored under the folder WebContent :

```
./WebContent
```

However, I wanted to respect the maven convention, so the entire folder had been moved the below one :

```
./src/main/webapp
```

Then the problem comes: **The application can be launched on server, but browser shows message "Forbidden".** And I don't know what does it mean and why does it appears. It used to show the home page content of `index.html`, with the URL `http://localhost:8080/jsr352/`. Here're some details that might be helpful :

- The project can be installed correctly using `mvn clean install`.
- The home page `index.xml`, deployment file `web.xml` and other web resources exist under `./target` folder and its subfolders.
- During the server start, there're no message of level *SEVERE*.

Can somebody give some helps ? Thanks.

---

Maven build's log using command `mvn clean install`:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Hibernate Search - JSR352 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ jsr352 ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/mincong/Documents/GitHub/gsoc-hsearch/jsr352/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ jsr352 ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ jsr352 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 23 source files to /Users/mincong/Documents/GitHub/gsoc-hsearch/jsr352/target/classes
[INFO] /Users/mincong/Documents/GitHub/gsoc-hsearch/jsr352/src/main/java/io/github/mincongh/batch/IndexingContext.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[INFO] /Users/mincong/Documents/GitHub/gsoc-hsearch/jsr352/src/main/java/io/github/mincongh/batch/IndexingContext.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ jsr352 ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/mincong/Documents/GitHub/gsoc-hsearch/jsr352/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ jsr352 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ jsr352 ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.6:war (default-war) @ jsr352 ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [jsr352] in [/Users/mincong/Documents/GitHub/gsoc-hsearch/jsr352/target/jsr352]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/Users/mincong/Documents/GitHub/gsoc-hsearch/jsr352/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [64 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /Users/mincong/Documents/GitHub/gsoc-hsearch/jsr352/target/jsr352.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ jsr352 ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/mincong/Documents/GitHub/gsoc-hsearch/jsr352/target/jsr352.war to /Users/mincong/.m2/repository/io/github/mincongh/jsr352/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/jsr352-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing /Users/mincong/Documents/GitHub/gsoc-hsearch/jsr352/pom.xml to /Users/mincong/.m2/repository/io/github/mincongh/jsr352/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/jsr352-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.548 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-06-14T00:34:11+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/215M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Web resources are found under the target folder. Some of them are omitted :

```
Mincongs-MBP:jsr352 mincong$ find ./target/jsr352
./target/jsr352
./target/jsr352/index.html
./target/jsr352/META-INF
./target/jsr352/WEB-INF
./target/jsr352/WEB-INF/beans.xml
./target/jsr352/WEB-INF/classes
./target/jsr352/WEB-INF/classes/...
./target/jsr352/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF
./target/jsr352/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/batch-jobs
./target/jsr352/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/batch-jobs/mass-index.xml
./target/jsr352/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
./target/jsr352/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml
./target/jsr352/WEB-INF/page
./target/jsr352/WEB-INF/page/search-results.jsp
./target/jsr352/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

WildFly 10.0 server's logs when app `jsr352` was launched.

```
00:07:46,024 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.1.Final
00:07:46,239 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
00:07:46,312 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) starting
00:07:47,496 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found jsr352.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called jsr352.war.dodeploy
00:07:47,496 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found mvnwebapp.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called mvnwebapp.war.dodeploy
00:07:47,555 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
00:07:47,582 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-7) XNIO version 3.3.4.Final
00:07:47,590 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-7) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.4.Final
00:07:47,636 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
00:07:47,662 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
00:07:47,675 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.18.Final
00:07:47,691 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.3.2.Final)
00:07:47,697 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
00:07:47,801 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
00:07:47,816 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
00:07:47,802 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
00:07:47,821 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
00:07:47,828 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.4.Final
00:07:47,835 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
00:07:47,851 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
00:07:47,860 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
00:07:47,860 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
00:07:47,860 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.3.15.Final starting
00:07:47,861 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.3.15.Final starting
00:07:47,871 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
00:07:47,872 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql
00:07:48,062 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path '/Users/mincong/Documents/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
00:07:48,085 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
00:07:48,086 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
00:07:48,093 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
00:07:48,093 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
00:07:48,219 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
00:07:48,385 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
00:07:48,385 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/MySqlDS-addresses]
00:07:48,546 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /Users/mincong/Documents/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments
00:07:48,547 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "mvnwebapp.war" (runtime-name: "mvnwebapp.war")
00:07:48,548 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "jsr352.war" (runtime-name: "jsr352.war")
00:07:48,817 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-3) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final
00:07:48,817 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-7) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final
00:07:49,002 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.3.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.4) 
00:07:49,847 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /mvnwebapp
00:07:50,662 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in /Users/mincong/Documents/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/jsr352.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.sun.tools.xjc_2.2.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
00:07:50,662 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jaxb-impl.jar in /Users/mincong/Documents/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/jsr352.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.sun.tools.xjc_2.2.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
00:07:50,663 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in /Users/mincong/Documents/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/jsr352.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.sun.tools.xjc_2.2.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
00:07:50,663 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry activation.jar in /Users/mincong/Documents/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/jsr352.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.sun.tools.xjc_2.2.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
00:07:50,717 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for us-address
00:07:50,886 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'jsr352.war#us-address'
00:07:50,917 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: us-address
    ...]
00:07:50,922 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment jsr352.war
00:07:51,030 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-3) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.3.Final
00:07:51,074 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.7.Final}
00:07:51,076 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
00:07:51,078 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
00:07:51,121 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'IndexSession' in deployment unit 'deployment "jsr352.war"' are as follows:

    java:global/jsr352/IndexSession!io.github.mincongh.session.IndexSession
    java:app/jsr352/IndexSession!io.github.mincongh.session.IndexSession
    java:module/IndexSession!io.github.mincongh.session.IndexSession
    java:global/jsr352/IndexSession
    java:app/jsr352/IndexSession
    java:module/IndexSession

00:07:51,121 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'BatchSession' in deployment unit 'deployment "jsr352.war"' are as follows:

    java:global/jsr352/BatchSession!io.github.mincongh.session.BatchSession
    java:app/jsr352/BatchSession!io.github.mincongh.session.BatchSession
    java:module/BatchSession!io.github.mincongh.session.BatchSession
    java:global/jsr352/BatchSession
    java:app/jsr352/BatchSession
    java:module/BatchSession

00:07:51,122 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'SearchSession' in deployment unit 'deployment "jsr352.war"' are as follows:

    java:global/jsr352/SearchSession!io.github.mincongh.session.SearchSession
    java:app/jsr352/SearchSession!io.github.mincongh.session.SearchSession
    java:module/SearchSession!io.github.mincongh.session.SearchSession
    java:global/jsr352/SearchSession
    java:app/jsr352/SearchSession
    java:module/SearchSession

00:07:51,142 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.deprecation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HHH90000001: Found usage of deprecated setting for specifying Scanner [hibernate.ejb.resource_scanner]; use [hibernate.archive.scanner] instead
00:07:51,153 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
00:07:51,387 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
00:07:51,389 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
00:07:51,391 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
00:07:51,393 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
00:07:51,393 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYWELD0006: Starting Services for CDI deployment: jsr352.war
00:07:51,466 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-5) WELD-000900: 2.3.2 (Final)
00:07:51,495 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYWELD0009: Starting weld service for deployment jsr352.war
00:07:51,739 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'jsr352.war#us-address'
00:07:51,993 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
00:07:52,265 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
00:07:52,322 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) Envers integration enabled? : true
00:07:52,820 INFO  [org.hibernate.search.engine.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) HSEARCH000034: Hibernate Search 5.5.1.Final
00:07:52,993 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
00:07:53,158 WARN  [org.hibernate.search.engine.impl.ConfigContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) HSEARCH000075: Configuration setting hibernate.search.lucene_version was not specified: using LUCENE_CURRENT.
00:07:54,961 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,962 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.OptimisticLockExceptionMapper from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,962 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.IllegalArgumentExceptionMapper from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,963 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.resources.unversioned.EntityResource from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,964 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.EntityExistsExceptionMapper from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,964 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.PessimisticLockExceptionMapper from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,964 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.ConversionExceptionMapper from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,964 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.resources.QueryResource from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,964 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.NamingExceptionMapper from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,965 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.PersistenceExceptionMapper from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,965 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.IllegalAccessExceptionMapper from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,965 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.IOExceptionMapper from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,965 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.InvocationTargetExceptionMapper from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,966 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.RollbackExceptionMapper from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,966 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.TransactionRequiredExceptionMapper from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,966 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.NoResultExceptionMapper from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,966 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.resources.PersistenceUnitResource from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,967 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.JAXBExceptionMapper from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,967 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.NoSuchMethodExceptionMapper from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,967 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.MalformedURLExceptionMapper from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,967 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.NonUniqueResultExceptionExceptionMapper from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,967 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.ClassNotFoundExceptionMapper from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,967 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.IllegalStateExceptionMapper from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,968 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.resources.unversioned.PersistenceUnitResource from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,968 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.resources.unversioned.QueryResource from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,968 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.resources.PersistenceResource from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,968 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.resources.SingleResultQueryResource from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,968 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.EntityNotFoundExceptionMapper from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,968 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.JPARSExceptionMapper from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,969 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.resources.EntityResource from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,969 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.resources.unversioned.SingleResultQueryResource from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,969 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.DatabaseExceptionMapper from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,969 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.QueryTimeoutExceptionMapper from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,969 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.JPARSConfigurationExceptionMapper from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:54,969 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.resources.unversioned.PersistenceResource from Application class org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication
00:07:55,207 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /jsr352
00:07:55,234 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "mvnwebapp.war" (runtime-name : "mvnwebapp.war")
00:07:55,235 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "jsr352.war" (runtime-name : "jsr352.war")
00:07:55,360 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
00:07:55,360 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
00:07:55,360 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) started in 9668ms - Started 532 of 806 services (394 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check project's [*Deployment Assembly*](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.2.0/NewAndNoteworthy/javaee.php) settings.

Alternatively you can let *m2e* set up your project via *Configure -> Convert to Maven project*. That might need new project... i.e. remove the project from the workspace, delete Eclipse files in the project folder (`.settings`, `.classpath`, `.project`, ...) and import the folder as new General project. Then use the *Convert to Maven project*.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. There's really a problem in _Deployment Assembly_, it said that `/WebContet` is missing. Then I removed it but it still doesn't work. I'll talk to my mentor tomorrow about your alternative plan and then give you a feedback :)

Comment: You need to set `src/main/webapp` to be the root of your deployment path. I.e. instead of deleting WebContent, you should have changed it.

Comment: The path `src/main/webapp` was already there as a _Source_ and it is pointed to `WEB-INF/classes` in _Deploy Path_. But it didn't solve the pb.

Comment: Ah OK ! Then Eclipse asks me to choose a deployment descriptor. So I chose the `/src/main/webapp`. Then a warning apprears `Connot find entry: "/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources"`.